# How do I get the radio input values from a nodelist?

Tags: javascript, dom

So Im trying to figure out why my radio inputs arent being recorded, which involves them being accessed through the DOM and turned into a nodelist. So what Im trying to do is get the radio input and save it into a (genre)variable. I get QuerySelectorAll returns a Nodelist which can be iterated, and so I did and then i set up a condition to see if its checked, and if it is, to return the value of the button to save into the genre valuable.  But when I console.log(genre) its empty. When I select a random radio and check it using chrome developer and i check its information for "checked" and its "value" it shows up as "true" and "the value that was clicked" but when I try to save it into the genre variable nothing shows up? I feel i like i did everything right but still nothing!.

Here's my jsfiddle with a simple example.
https://jsfiddle.net/Jbautista1056/jwg5dm4k/12/

```js
       let title = document.getElementById("title").value
   let status = document.getElementById("status").value
   let radioContainer = document.getElementById("Radio-Container")
   let radios = radioContainer.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]') // =>returns NodeList which acts an array
   let genre = ''

   for (i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked === "true") {
        genre = radios[i].value
    } 

 }


alert(genre)
```

Comment: There is no change event, code runs when page is loading. You have an error in the console.

Comment: Yeah, you need an Event. That overwrites to the end of the loop anyways.